# jquery other page element inactive after $("#div").show()

Tags: jquery

how can i do. i have many html elements on page. after clicking on html button, i want that, my special div showed, but, other html are inactive. for example, textareas not editable, buttons are not clickable.

thanks

Forget say "SpecialDiv" also contain buttons, selects, textareas etc. they must be "abled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a separate, transparent `<div>` that covers the entire page.

You're probably looking for [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).

Comment: that will also require a hack (can't remember what it's called) to deal with the bizarre way that `<select>` elements work in IE6

Comment: @Pointy: You're referring to the `<iframe>` hack.  The examples I mentioned already do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourDiv').show();
$('input, textarea, button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's a little vague, but

```
function zap() {
  $('#magicDiv').show();
  $('input, button, textarea, select').attr({disabled: true});
}
function unzap() {
  $('#magicDiv').hide();
  $('input, button, textarea, select').attr({disabled: false});
}
```

Now if you need to worry about *other* things that might disable inputs, you could do this:

```
function zap() {
  $('#magicDiv').show();
  $('input, button, select, textarea').each(function(_, elem) {
    if (!elem.disabled) {
      $(elem).data('zapped', true).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
}
function unzap() {
  $('#magicDiv').hide();
  $('input, button, select, textarea').each(function(_, elem) {
    if ($(elem).data('zapped')) {
      $(elem).data('zapped', false).attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If a button was previously disabled, this will still reenable it.

Comment: sorry, i forgot tell you that, in magicDiv also contains buttons, selects, ... etc.

Comment: @loviji: You can add `.not('#magicDiv *')`.  However, you should probably use a modal dialog plugin instead.